# Open-ended feature requests: Post suggestions in question or as answers?

Tags: discussion, meta, feature-request-process

Let's say I have a fairly open-ended feature request of the form:

> I see **X** as a problem and would like to solve it.
>
> I believe it could be solved by **A**. Alternatively, I believe it could be solved by the significantly different solution **B**. There may also be other solutions that I have not thought of.

Is it more useful to:

1. Post **A** and **B** in the question, or
2. Post **A** and **B** as two separate self-answers, or
3. Tag [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) instead (possibly in combination with one of the above), reword as a question (e.g. "Is this really a problem and are there any solutions?"), then either present a new [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) once an acceptable solution has been hashed out, or give up if the idea has been rejected.

The goals are to get the most meaning out of votes while balancing noise and conciseness: For example, option 1 presents a conflict if a user agrees with the problem but not the proposed solutions, while option 2 leaves the problem and solution separate at the expense of potential extra "noise" as answers (if it's an XY problem it separates the X from the Y) -- although it does allow new answers that respond to the underlying **X** (in the case where it's not really a problem after all) to cover the question 100%. Option 3 seems more "philosophically" correct in that if it is open-ended it is more of a discussion than a specific feature request.

What's the best way to pose a request like this?

Comment: Clearly, this is off-topic because it belongs on Meta-Meta StackExchange.

Comment: @AlexisKing [Why doesn't Meta Stack Overflow have a Meta?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99426/165773)

Comment: @gnat Hah, I didn't expect anyone to legitimately ask that question.

Comment: @AlexisKing I am starting to resent the fact that [a relevant XKCD exists for everything](http://xkcd.com/917/).

Comment: @JasonC There's even [more than one](https://xkcd.com/1447/)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I'd say it depends on the request but doesn't matter too much. I think your options #1 and #2 generally get to the same place. (If you don't post the two ideas of how to implement the feature as self-answers, it's very likely that one or both will be posted as answers by someone else.) Posting the two self-answers does give you a nice starting point for less noisy voting, but might stifle discussion of the validity of those ideas.

It basically depends on how confident you are in your request. If you've thought about it a lot, don't think anyone will disagree with the problem you're trying to solve, and think that there are really only one or two viable ways to implement your request, then I think it's fine to define the problem in the question and self-answer with your solutions.

If you think that the problem is contentious, or that there might be alternative solutions that you haven't thought of, post your possible solutions in the question and see what the community thinks.

If you're really just at the beginning stages of thinking about this, and don't actually know if the problem you're thinking about exists, or if it's important, post a discussion question.

These are all just my personal opinions, and like I said, I don't think it actually matters too much. Coherent logic and clear proposals are more important than the precise format they're presented in. :)

Comment: Seems like a reasonable set of guidelines to me. Thanks. I overthink everything, rules of thumb(s?) make me happy.